# Telegram bot developed using telebot library in python won't work in telegram channels?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I build a simple telegram bot using the telebot library and it's successfully working! then I added the bot into a telegram channel it's not working! also, I added the same bot to a telegram group then it's working! I'm a little bit confused why the telegram bot is not working in my telegram channel? Can anyone help me through this?

Here is my code.

```
import telebot

from constatnts import API_KEY

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY, parse_mode=None)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'hello'])
def send_help_message(msg):
    bot.reply_to(msg, "Hello this is test bot for ml5")
    print(msg)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.content_type == 'text' )
def send_message(msg):
    bot.reply_to(msg, "Gotcha")

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import telebot

from constatnts import API_KEY

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY, parse_mode=None)


@bot.channel_post_handler(commands=['help', 'hello'])
def send_help_message(msg):
    bot.reply_to(msg, "Hello this is test bot for ml5")
    print(msg)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.content_type == 'text' )
def send_message(msg):
    bot.reply_to(msg, "Gotcha")

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, messages and channel posts have different handlers:

```
@bot.channel_post_handler(commands=['help', 'hello'])
```

Also do make sure the bot is an administrator of the channel.